# Error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 when trying to parse json for http request

Tags: node.js, json, puppeteer

I am new to node.js, and would appreciate some assistance.

I am currently writing code, that simply fetches a request id, via parsing the json, and then relays that id over to another http call, to derive a token, to then input into html via puppeteer.

*Currently, when I attempt to parse json via nodejs's json parse command, I receive the error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

My intention is to derive the value of attribute 'request', so It can be referenced as a constant in the subsequent steps.

However, I receive the above error.

The JSON format looks like this when I make the http request.

{"status":1,"request":"123452590"}

(Request value in this test case would be 123452590 which is what I want to obtain and store as constant

Any help would be really appreciated.

Currently, the code is structured in the following manner:

````
    method: 'userrecaptcha',
    key: xxx
   googlekey: 'xxx',
    pageurl: 'http://test.ca', 
    json: 1
  };
  var request = require('request');
  const response = await request.post('http://2captcha.com/in.php', {form: formData});
  const requestId = JSON.parse(response).request;
  console.log (requestId)
  async function pollForRequestResults(key, id, retries = 30, interval = 1500, delay = 15000) {
    await timeout(delay);
    return poll({
      taskFn: requestCaptchaResults(key, id),
      interval,
      retries
    });
  }

  function requestCaptchaResults(key, requestId) {
    const url = `http://2captcha.com/res.php?key=${key}&action=get&id=${requestId}&json=1`;
    return async function() {
      return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
        const rawResponse = await request.get(url);
        const resp = JSON.parse(rawResponse);
        if (resp.status === 0) return reject(resp.request);
        resolve(resp.request);
      });
    }
  }

  const timeout = millis => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis))

})()```

const requestId = JSON.parse(response).request;
````

Comment: The problem is that response isn't text, I think you want response.body or response.content. Also try [this solution](https://github.com/pguardiario/captchas), it should be easier.